# iPhone OpenCV face detection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opencv, face-detection

When I execute

```
self.model = (CvHaarClassifierCascade *) cvLoad([file cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], 0, 0, 0);
```

I found following error.

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The node does not represent a user object (unknown type?)) in cvRead, file /Users/robin/Projects/OpenCVForiPhone/opencv/opencv/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp, line 4858
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: That error means that OpenCV is not able to recognize the data of the XML file. Check whether you are passing the correct file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this guide:
  http://niw.at/articles/2009/03/14/using-opencv-on-iphone/en

Hope it will give u some direction :]